# Angular JS circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I'm trying to port some java to an a cordova app using angular and have come across the a circular dependency issue - which has been asked frequently, but in all honesty I'm still none the wiser.

I have two objects - a Celestial Body and an Orbit object which can reference each other.

```java
class Orbit {
    double a; // Semi Major axis
    double e; // Eccentricity
    Body primary; // The primary body around which the orbit is centred

    double getPeriod() {
        if (a < 0) {
            return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        } else {
            return 2 * Math.PI * Math.sqrt(a * a * a / primary.mu);
        }
    }
}

class Body {
    double mu; // Gravitational parameter
    String name;
    double radius; // Surface radius
    Orbit orbit;

    double getSphereOfInfluence() {
        if (orbit.primary == null) {
            return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        } else {
            return orbit.a * Math.pow(mu / orbit.primary.mu, .4);
        }
    }
}
```

If we take the moon as an example, the Body "Moon" has an orbit whose primary is the "Earth", which in turn has an orbit whose primary is the "Sun", etc.

The benefit [IMO] is that I can have a set of static objects so if I create a number of orbit objects, they're all using the same primary body and not duplicating all the properties. It also means I can walk through up through the system reliably.

I've seen various comments saying the circular dependencies are "bad", and I've read [Misko's blog about the subject](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/), but am struggling with two things - why are they "bad", and how would I refactor my code into "good" code using his A, B, C methodology.

**Update - what I've ended up with**

```js
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.service("Bodies", function(Body, Orbit) {
  this.KERBOL = new Body({name: "Kerbol", mu: 1.17233279483249E+18, period: 432000, radius: 261600000});
  this.KERBIN = new Body({name: "Kerbin", mu: 3531600000000, period: 21600, radius: 600000, orbit:
      new Orbit({a: 13599840256, e: 0, primary: this.KERBOL})
    });

  this.find = function(name) {
    var found = null;

    angular.forEach(this, function(item, key) {
      if ((found == null) && (item instanceof Body) && (item.name === name)) {
        found = item;
      }
    });

    console.log("Found body: " + JSON.stringify(found));
    return found;
  };
})

.factory("Body", function() {
  function Body(params) {
    if (params) {
      this.mu = params.mu;
      this.name = params.name;
      this.period = params.period;
      this.radius = params.radius;
      this.orbit = params.orbit;
    }
  };

  Body.prototype = {
    get primary() { return this.orbit.primary; },

    getEscapeVelocity: function() {
      return Math.sqrt(2 * this.mu / this.radius);
    },

    getOrderValue: function() {
      var v = this.orbit.a;

      var body = this;
      while ((body = body.orbit.primary) !== null) {
        v += body.orbit.a;
      }

      return v;
    },

    getSphereOfInfluence: function() {
      if (this.orbit.primary == null) {
        return Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
      } else {
        return this.orbit.a * Math.pow(this.mu / this.orbit.primary.mu, .4);
      }
    },

    getSurfaceGravity: function() {
      return this.mu / (this.radius * this.radius);
    },

    getSynchronousAlt: function() {
      return this.getSynchronousRadius() - this.radius;
    },

    getSynchronousRadius: function() {
      throw "Not implemented";
    }
  };

  return (Body);
})

.factory("Orbit", function(Body) {
  function Orbit(params) {
    if (params) {
      this.a = params.a;
      this.e = params.e;
      this.epoch = params.epoch;
      this.i = params.i;
      this.omega = params.omega;
      this.lan = params.lan;
      this.M0 = params.M0;
      this.M = params.M;
      this.primary = params.primary;
    }
  };

  Orbit.prototype = {
  };

  return (Orbit);
})
});
```

Comment: Surprise: Java code in a javascript question ;) If we could see some actual javascript code, that would help a lot.

Comment: Fair point - I hadn't posted the JS because I suppose I was more interested in how one would have refactored the code , but then the question shouldn't have been javascript. Anyhow, merely asking the question gave me a thought, and I realised the problem was that the static Body declarations were what was causing the error, so I moved them into a separate factory. I'll post the resulting code and see if it makes anyone cry!

Comment: And where is the circular dependency? Circular dependency means that **instance** A refers to instance B and that in turn refers A. You have no such situation in this code as far as I see. For me that code looks pretty OK.

Comment: Gah - my brain apparently crashed that day, and this is the first opportunity I've had to get back - I posted the code I got working by mistake, not the code with the cdep error. Basically I got it working, but with (IMO) some compromises.

Answer (score -1):

If you can do this using c++, you could do a Body* atribute in Orbit and a Orbit* atribute in Body, then you stop the multi-reference.
To use that you only need to do: myBody = new Body();

Anyway, I do not think two different classes referencing each other is the best way... think another way.